# How do I retrieve bitmap button name in wx python

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

This is my code.

```
 self.bid += 1
 name = "ct %d" % self.bid
 self.newct = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, pic, pos = pos, size=(33,33), style = wx.NO_BORDER, name = name)
 dbox=wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Enter the Value", 'Button Info', "")
    if dbox.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
        value=dbox.GetValue()
 btdict = {'button id': self.bid, 'value': value}


 self.newct.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip('ID: %d, Value: %d' %(self.bid, value)))
```

How do I retrieve the name afterwards?

I am working a tool that requires a dynamic number of bitmap buttons to be created which can be dragged around around the panel. When I have multiple buttons, it becomes very difficult to distinguish one from another so I was hoping to add a tool-tip to each button that shows the button name.

Also I am getting error "TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not unicode" here

```
self.newct.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip('ID: %d, Value: %d' %(self.bid, value))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For second problem, `value` is not a number, but a string. `%d` requires integer. Try either `value = int(dbox.GetValue())` or `self.newct.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip('ID: %d, Value: %s' %(self.bid, value)))`

Comment: Thanks Feniko, worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name of button, just use `GetName()` method. The name of the button can be set either in constructor (`wx.BitmapButton(self,..., name = someName)`) or after creating the button, you can use `SetName()` method. In your code, `value` seems to be the new name of your button so you should set it or create the button after getting the `value`.